# How to Prioritize Python Module Suggestions in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VS code suggestions are not in expected order

I’m using VS Code for Python development and I’ve noticed an issue with the order of the suggestions. For example When I import the OS module and type ‘os.’, a list of suggestions appears. However, the initial suggestions seem unrelated to the OS module, such as ‘add’, ‘join’, etc. It’s only when I scroll down the list that I start seeing suggestions related to the OS module. I would prefer these OS module-related suggestions to appear at the top of the list. How can I adjust the settings in VS Code to achieve this?

[image: Current behaviour]

[image: Want these suggestions to be on top]

Comment: The question is why these suggestions appear at all. They should not. What is the complete code contained in this file? What VS Code extensions and settings are you using? (I'm not an expert in VS Code so can't tell exactly what information is required to debug this issue.)

Comment: If it helps, I don't experience that. My vscode is pretty close to default config, as I mainly use wing. Could it be something silly like os = [] somewhere in that file?

Comment: its not related to os only its for all modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the following setting

```json
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom",
```

[image]